# Shorter name for PRC than 中华人民共和国

Tags: place-names, abbreviations

Is there a shorter term for the People's Republic of China (中华人民共和国)? Seven syllables is quite a mouthful. There's 中国 and 大陆 but they aren't quite the same.

- 中国 (China) can include the Taiwan, the Republic of China's territory, under a One China principle
- 大陆 (mainland) doesn't include Hong Kong and Macau

Comment: Some Chinese consider Taiwan is part of China and some don't. For all other countries, 中国 is officially the People's Republic of China.

Comment: In special context, you can use "共和国". For example, "共和国之光".

Answer (score 1):

Following are the internationally recognized terms used. They should be very clear for you to find out the English equivalent:

- 中(华人民共和)国 — () usually omitted unless very formal
- [中国]大陆 — [] not often omitted
- 台湾{地区} / {中国}台湾 — {} showing political preference
- {中国}香港 — {} showing political preference
- {中国}澳门 — {} showing political preference

Answer (score -1):

[支那](https://www.google.com/search?ei=OMxcX60g6pmvvA-mnKioCg&q=%E6%94%AF%E9%82%A3&oq=%E6%94%AF%E9%82%A3&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDDICCAAyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyAggAMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgIIADIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAOgQIABBHUKDOK1j71Ctg7t8raABwAngAgAGKAYgBvgGSAQMxLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwitnIbZ2-PrAhXqzIsBHSYOCqUQ4dUDCAw) is one of them but it is considered offensive.

Comment: Calling China 支那 is as offensive as calling African Nigger. Do be careful.

Answer (score -2):

Fortunately, there is already an entry on wikipedia here [zh-cn](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%B1%E8%99%9F) and here [en-us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_China), plus many other language pages. You will get to know all alternative names of China, both contemporary and conventional.